# Array with array of hashes breaks code in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, hash

I am new ruby and working on terminal game. 
I have an array of my deck_of_cards

```
deck_of_cards =[ {:card=>"2C",:value=>2}, {:card=>"3C",:value=>3}, {:card=>"4C",:value=>4}, {:card=>"5C",:value=>5}, {:card=>"6C",:value=>6}, {:card=>"7C",:value=>7}, {:card=>"8C",:value=>8}, {:card=>"9C",:value=>9}, {:card=>"10C",:value=>10}, {:card=>"JC",:value=>11}, {:card=>"QC",:value=>12}, {:card=>"KC",:value=>13}, {:card=>"AC",:value=>14},
             {:card=>"2D",:value=>2}, {:card=>"3D",:value=>3}, {:card=>"4D",:value=>4}, {:card=>"5D",:value=>5}, {:card=>"6D",:value=>6}, {:card=>"7D",:value=>7}, {:card=>"8D",:value=>8}, {:card=>"9D",:value=>9}, {:card=>"10D",:value=>10}, {:card=>"JD",:value=>11}, {:card=>"QD",:value=>12}, {:card=>"KD",:value=>13}, {:card=>"AD",:value=>14},
             {:card=>"2H",:value=>2}, {:card=>"3H",:value=>3}, {:card=>"4H",:value=>4}, {:card=>"5H",:value=>5}, {:card=>"6H",:value=>6}, {:card=>"7H",:value=>7}, {:card=>"8H",:value=>8}, {:card=>"9H",:value=>9}, {:card=>"10H",:value=>10}, {:card=>"JH",:value=>11}, {:card=>"QH",:value=>12}, {:card=>"KH",:value=>13}, {:card=>"AH",:value=>14},
             {:card=>"2S",:value=>2}, {:card=>"3S",:value=>3}, {:card=>"4S",:value=>4}, {:card=>"5S",:value=>5}, {:card=>"6S",:value=>6}, {:card=>"7S",:value=>7}, {:card=>"8S",:value=>8}, {:card=>"9S",:value=>9}, {:card=>"10S",:value=>10}, {:card=>"JS",:value=>11}, {:card=>"QS",:value=>12}, {:card=>"KS",:value=>13}, {:card=>"AS",:value=>14}]
```

I then shuffle the deck_of_cards and deal to player_1 =[] and player_2 = [] via .slice!

My problem is that after I run my logic tests

```
until player1 == [] || player2 == []
    player1_battle = []
    player2_battle = []
    player1_battle_value = []
    player2_battle_value = []
    puts player1.slice(0).class
    puts player2.slice(0).class
    player1_battle << player1.slice!(0)
    player2_battle << player2.slice!(0)
    puts player1_battle.class
    puts player2_battle.class

    player1_battle_value << player1_battle.map{|h| h[:value].to_i}
    player2_battle_value << player2_battle.map{|h| h[:value].to_i}
    puts "Dealer draws #{player1_battle}" #shows each players card on the table
    puts "You draw #{player2_battle}" #takes top card out of player array
    puts player1_battle_value
    puts player2_battle_value
    puts player1_battle_value <=> player2_battle_value
    battle_value = player1_battle_value <=> player2_battle_value
    puts battle_value
     if battle_value == 1
      player1 << player1_battle
      player1 << player2_battle
      puts "Dealer Wins!"
```

My player_1 array then breaks at the

```
player1_battle_value << player1_battle.map{|h| h[:value].to_i}
```

once the player_1 array becomes

```
[[{:card=>"KD", :value=>13}], [{:card=>"AC", :value=>14}], [{:card=>"4S", :value=>4}]]
```

and the first index is now and array with a hash the .map method breaks into

```
:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
from terminal_war.rb:65:in `block in <main>'
from terminal_war.rb:65:in `map'
from terminal_war.rb:65:in `<main>'
```

I know that my code is not great but is there a better way to test the :value of against the :card and keep the code from breaking after 24-26 times through the loop? Once all of the hashes within the array become arrays with hashes the code breaks.

I hope that I provided enough info, thank you.

Comment: You should show the rest of your code.

Comment: I put the code in a gist at https://gist.github.com/mdorrance/5749652 Thank you for looking at the question!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> player1_battle_value << player1_battle.map{|h| h[:value].to_i}
> ```
>
> once the player_1 array becomes
>
> ```
> [{:card=>"KD", :value=>13}, [{:card=>"AC", :value=>14}], [{:card=>"4S", :value=>4}]]
> ```

Shouldn't you be using `concat`?

```
player1_battle_value.concat(player1_battle.map{|h| h[:value].to_i})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I changed it and the error is the same `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
 from terminal_war.rb:65:in `block in <main>'
 from terminal_war.rb:65:in `map'
 from terminal_war.rb:65:in `<main>'

Comment: once my array of hashes becomes an array of array of hashes it breaks

Comment: Just edited player_1 array to show the array of arrays with hashes. Sorry for any confusion, this is my first post :)

Comment: @sierra2: have you changed other similar references? Your problem comes from changing your data structure. Keep your data structure they way it's supposed to be by using the correct operators and functions.

Comment: I am working on that. I am new and I need to do some more research on the right functions to and operators. Thank you.